# Why can't I download anymore apps on my iPad?

Tags: applications, ipad, disk-space

I think I don't have anymore space. So what do I do now? Help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You're going to need to provide more details about your problem to get someone to help you: specific error messages, things you've tried, etc. You can edit your question and add more info.

Answer (score 1):

As [noted in another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68885/10167), you'll need to remove some data if you want to install new apps. What you remove really depends on what's taking up lots of space — it might be apps (games in particular tend to be large), videos or music.

You can get a good overview of what's taking up space on your device by going to **Settings → General → Usage**. You should see a breakdown of how much storage each app is taking up. You can also remove apps from this screen, or if tap on the Music or Videos apps, you have the option of removing some media files more granularly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start with removing some of your unwanted apps.

To delete: Press and hold any of the app icons on home screen, then press the small cross button at the upper right hand corner of your unwanted app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to go to settings, then you go to " General Usage " to see what are the apps who are taking to much space on your device. Then you just delete the unwanted apps.

Answer (score -2):

You have to register with the iTunes Store to be able to download.